# How to pass string-array resource to java class in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm learning input controls in the android studio. I used string-array XML tag in strings.xml to display elements in a spinner. For passing the arguments in the java class when using R.array.phnLabels, the ide shows error and while running the code, the app keeps stopping in the virtual phone. Below are my source code and resource files.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Spinner spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        if(spinner != null)
            spinner.setOnItemClickListener((AdapterView.OnItemClickListener) this);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.phnLabels,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        if(spinner != null)
            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Below is the string.xml file

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Input Controls</string>
    <string-array name="phnLabels">
        <item>Work</item>
        <item>Home</item>
        <item>Mobile</item>
    </string-array>
</resources>
```

And below is the layout View component for the spinner

```
 <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="298dp"/>
```

The errors showing in the Logcat

```
2020-07-02 21:06:26.179 9134-9134/com.example.inputcontrols E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.inputcontrols, PID: 9134
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.inputcontrols/com.example.inputcontrols.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.inputcontrols.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.example.inputcontrols.MainActivity cannot be cast to android.widget.AdapterView$OnItemClickListener
        at com.example.inputcontrols.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:25)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6679)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2618
```

Comment: Please post the error from logcat that you are getting, so we can find the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Either you pass into your layout XML file:

```
<Spinner 
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
        android:entries="@array/phnLabels"
    />
```

or you can get the string array in java class using:

```
String[] albums = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.phnLabels);
```

set the adapter in android class like:

```
 List<String> albumsList = Arrays.asList(albums);
    ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
               albumsList); //selected item will look like a spinner set from XML
    spinnerArrayAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout
                                                         .simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);
```

Let me know it works or not.

Comment: still the app keeps closing without starting

Comment: can you share the log message?